# WPFのTextBoxでAcceptsReturnをtrueにしたときCtrl+Enterで改行ができない

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

いつもお世話になっております．

WPFでプログラミング用のテキストエディタを実装していて，Ctrl+Dで文を複製する機能を作ろうとしていたのですが，文が複製される際に改行が入らなかったのです．
調べていくうちに，Ctrl+Enterでは改行できないことがわかりました．(Ctrl+Dコマンドを実行際に複製する文をTextBoxに送っているのでコマンドが実行されている間はCtrlキーが押されている)
AcceptsReturnプロパティはTrueに設定しているので，Ctrlキーが押されていなければちゃんと改行ができます．

Ctrl+Enterで改行ができないなら，InputManagerでEnterキーを送っても改行が入力されないことはわかるのですが，TextCompositionManagerでTextを送る際に”\r\n”を送っても改行が入力されないのが，よくわかりません．

どのようにすればCtrlキーが押された状態で改行を入力できるようになるのでしょうか．

開発環境はWindows 10(1803)，
VisualStudio 2017 ，
.NET Framework 4.5です．

以下ソースコードです

```
class Editor : TextBox {
        //コンストラクタやほかの処理は省略

        private void SendText(string text)
        {
                TextCompositionManager.StartComposition(new 
                TextComposition(InputManager.Current, this, text));
        }

        private void SendKey(Key key)
        {
                PresentationSource presentationSource = 
PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(new 
                KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, presentationSource, 100, key)
                {
                        RoutedEvent = PreviewKeyDownEvent
                });
        }

        public void Duplicate() //Ctrl+D
        {
                int current_line = GetCurrentLineNumber();
                int current_start = SelectionStart;
                string duptext = GetLineText(current_line);
                SendText(Environment.NewLine + duptext);
                SelectionStart = current_start;
        }
}
```

InputManagerやTextCompositionManagerを採用した理由については，将来RichTextBoxにコードを移植した際に，Textプロパティを直接書き換える方法使った場合，Rtf値がリセットされて色情報が消えてしまうからです．
Ctrl+Dを押したときのイベント捕捉はXAMLのKeyBindingsで行っています．

よろしくお願いします．

Comment: これかもしれません。[C#/XAML: WPF の TextBox を複数行入力（マルチライン）に対応させる](https://blog.t5o.me/post/20140304/c-sharp-xaml-textbox-multiline.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．
AcceptsReturnプロパティをTrueに設定したうえで現状の問題が発生しております．

Comment: 記事では TextWrapping も設定するよう書かれているのですが、それも設定されているか、あるいはその設定も関係無いなら、対象部分のXAMLとソースコードを追記した方が回答が付きやすいでしょう。他にはこんな記事も。[C#WPFの道#24！TextBlock,TextBoxの改行と文字の加工を解説](https://anderson02.com/cs/wpf/wpf-24/#i-2), [方法: 複数行の TextBox コントロールを作成する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-multiline-textbox-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> どのようにすればCtrlキーが押された状態で改行を入力できるようになるのでしょうか．

プログラムコードで[強引に改行](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549299)できます。

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //MyTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown;  // PreviewKeyDownではCtrl+Enterで改行できない
            MyTextBox.KeyDown += MyTextBox_KeyDown;
            InputManagerButton.Click += InputManagerButton_Click;
        }

        private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
            //Ctrlキーが押されている時、強引に改行する
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                var caretIndex = textBox.CaretIndex;
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Insert(caretIndex, Environment.NewLine);
                textBox.CaretIndex = caretIndex + Environment.NewLine.Length;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.D && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                //テキストを末尾にコピペする(+改行テスト)
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text
                    + string.Format("\r\n改行する{0}", Environment.NewLine)
                    + @"\r\n" + "改行しない" + "\\r\\n"
                    + textBox.Text;
            }
        }

        private void InputManagerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyTextBox.Focus();
            var enterEvent = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Enter);
            enterEvent.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(enterEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="InputManagerButton" Content="Emulate InputManager"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

しかし下記の理由が分かりません。

1. Ctrl+Dで文を複製する機能を作ろうとしていたのですが，文が複製される際に改行が入らなかった
2. TextCompositionManagerでTextを送る際に"\r\n"を送っても改行が入力されない

もしかして文を複製する時に`PreviewKeyDown`イベントから`InputManager`を使って、過去のキーストロークを再現しようとしていますか？
その場合は`InputManager`を採用した理由とサンプルコードを質問に追記していただくと回答しやすいです。
特に理由がなければ回答コードのように、Textプロパティを直接書き換えるべきだと思います。(プロパティを直接書き換えればCtrl+Enter問題も自動的に解決します)

`\r\n`を送れば改行されるはずですが、`@"\r\n"`やファイルから読み込んだ"\r\n"という文字列(string型としては`\\r\\n`でエスケープされる)の場合は改行されません。
追加の条件がある場合はこちらも追記をお願いします。

蛇足ですが、サンプルコードでCtrlキーを押下しながら`InputManagerButton`をクリックした場合は、`PreviewKeyDown`イベントではフォーカス移動した瞬間に`Key.LeftCtrl`がMyTextBox_KeyDownイベントの引数に送られてEnterキーのイベントが処理されませんでした。

ちなみに[TextWrapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_WordWrap)プロパティはテキストの横幅がTextBoxより長くなった時の文字列折り返し方法を指定するものなので、今回の質問とは関係ないはずです。

Comment: 質問へのご回答ありがとうございます．Textプロパティの中身を直接書き換える方法を完全に失念しておりました．ソースコードとInputManagerを採用した理由については編集で追加しておきます